# How to set rotations to 0,0,0 in 3ds max for exporting in unity?

Tags: unity, 3dsmax

I'm a modeler in 3ds max and the unity programmer ask me that the object must have:

- pivot with Y up
- rotations at 0,0,0

but every object that I export in fbx he says don't have rotations at 0,0,0.
I tryed different solutions as:
- reset xform
- freeze rotation
- rotation to zero
- $.rotation = eulerangles 0 0 0

but in unity he have values like this
[4.577637e-05, -1.525879e-05, 0] or [-90, 1.525879e-05, 0] and so on

It's a problem that can I fix in max or the programmer has to fix it in unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a script for max called *[XNA Utilities MAXScript for 3DS Max](http://metlab.cse.msu.edu/xna3ds.html)* which solves your problem. 3DS Max operates with two pivot points, which causes this value when importing to other 3D packages.

Althogh it was made for XNA development it works for Unity aswell. Just run this script before exporting the FBX file and you should get an imported mesh rotated to [0,0,0].

All credit to [Dr. Charles B. Owen](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cbowen/)

I also point my Y axis on the model up, and export with the Y-up setting on the FBX export.